# Serial communication not working when class is instantiated in Arduino Environment

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to write code for my Arduino Mega to communicate with ADXL345 accelerometer using c++ style library. 
This is my Accelerometer.h file:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#define ADXL345 (0x53) // I2C Address of ADXL345 accelerometer

struct Acceleration
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

class Accelerometer
{
  public:
    Accelerometer(void);              // Constructor
    Acceleration readData(void);                  // Read sensor data
  private:
    char buffer[6];   // Buffer to store data (x, y, z: LSB and MSB of each)
    char DATA_FORMAT; // Address of DATA_FORMAT Register
    char POWER_CTL;   // Address of POWER_CTL Register
    char DATAX0;      // Address of X-Axis LSB Data
    char DATAX1;      // Address of X-Axis MSB Data
    char DATAY0;      // Address of Y-Axis LSB Data
    char DATAY1;      // Address of Y-Axis MSB Data
    char DATAZ0;      // Address of Z-Axis LSB Data
    char DATAZ1;      // Address of Z-Axis MSB Data
    void writeToAccelerometer(char address, char value);
    void readFromAccelerometer(char address, int numOfBytes);
};
```

And this is my Accelerometer.cpp file:

```
#include "Accelerometer.h"
#include <Wire.h>

Accelerometer::Accelerometer()
{
  Wire.begin();                                // Initialize I2C bus
  writeToAccelerometer(DATA_FORMAT, 0x01);     // +/- 4g range 
  writeToAccelerometer(POWER_CTL, 0x08);       // Measurement Mode

  DATA_FORMAT = 0x31;      // Address of DATA_FORMAT Register
  POWER_CTL   = 0x2D;      // Address of POWER_CTL Register
  DATAX0      = 0x32;      // Address of X-Axis LSB Data
  DATAX1      = 0x33;      // Address of X-Axis MSB Data
  DATAY0      = 0x34;      // Address of Y-Axis LSB Data
  DATAY1      = 0x35;      // Address of Y-Axis MSB Data
  DATAZ0      = 0x36;      // Address of Z-Axis LSB Data
  DATAZ1      = 0x37;      // Address of Z-Axis MSB Data
}

void Accelerometer::writeToAccelerometer(char address, char value) 
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345); // start transmission to ADXL345 
  Wire.write(address);             // send register address
  Wire.write(value);               // send value to write
  Wire.endTransmission();          // end transmission
}

void Accelerometer::readFromAccelerometer(char address, int numOfBytes)
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345); // start transmission to ADXL345 
  Wire.write(address);             // send register address
  Wire.endTransmission();          // end transmission

  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345);          // start transmission to ADXL345
  Wire.requestFrom(ADXL345, numOfBytes);    // request some bytes from device

  int i = 0;
  while(Wire.available())           // while there is data
  { 
    buffer[i] = Wire.read();        // receive a byte and save it in the buffer
    i++;
  }
  Wire.endTransmission();           // end transmission
}

Acceleration Accelerometer::readData()
{
  Acceleration R;
  readFromAccelerometer(DATAX0, 6);          // Read data from sensor

  // Merge of data and conversion to int format
  int x_acceleration = (((int)buffer[1]) << 8) | buffer[0];
  int y_acceleration = (((int)buffer[3]) << 8) | buffer[2];
  int z_acceleration = (((int)buffer[5]) << 8) | buffer[4];

  R.x = x_acceleration*0.0078;
  R.y = x_acceleration*0.0078;
  R.z = x_acceleration*0.0078;

  return R;
}
```

I'm using this library im my Arduino sketch with this code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Accelerometer.h"

Accelerometer accel;
Acceleration Racc;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);   // Start serial for outbut at 9600 bps
}

void loop()
{
  Racc = accel.readData();

  // Print data
  Serial.print("ACCELERATION - X: ");
  Serial.print( Racc.x );
  Serial.print(" G / Y: ");
  Serial.print( Racc.y );
  Serial.print(" G / Z: ");
  Serial.print( Racc.z );
  Serial.print(" G\n");

  delay(100);
}
```

This code is compilated without erros. However, because of the instantiation of Accelerometer class, Serial communication is not working (I can't see any text in Serial Monitor). When I remove the class instance of the code (letting just Serial communication in code), I can see what is print in Serial Monitor.

Does anybody have any idea about what is going on? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

As the ADXL345 can operate either SPI or I2C it needs to be configured, as such. In your case of trying to use it as I2C, the CS of the ADXL345 need to be tied to 3.3V

> I2C mode is enabled if the CS pinis tied high to VDD I/O. The CS pin
>   should always be tied high to VDD I/O or be driven by an external
>   controller because there is nodefault mode if the CS pin is left
>   unconnected. Therefore, not taking these precautions may result in an
>   inability to ommunicatewith the part.

Where in your above code I do not see any pins configured as output to drive the CS.

It has been my experience that when the I2C (wire.h) library is not properly connected to a device it can be blocking. Which is similar to your described symptom here.

---

You may want to reference your code against others, such as https://github.com/jenschr/Arduino-libraries/tree/master/ADXL345. which appears to fully support the many features of the ADXL345 over I2C

Comment: I may also want add a max timeout to the "while(Wire.available())" so that it does not block for ever. If the I2C does not work correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was making a fool mistake - in constructor I was calling writeToAccelerometer method before assigning values for DATA_FORMAT and POWER_CTL. I fixed this (doind the assignments before) but it still not working.

About this consideration of CS, I defined pin 53 as an output and made digitalWrite(53, HIGH);. Is this sufficient?